# Save contents of ArrayController to file

Tags: macos, applescript

I am making a cocoa applescript osx app in Xcode 5

I have a Table View that is updated with the current play time of a quicktime file with each button press using an Array Controller. All is working well but I am stuck on how to then save the results of the Table view to file, preferably a .csv

I have been trying to research ways to do this but most of the tutorials I find relate to iOS.
I have researched using NSStrings and writeToFile but am having trouble filling in the blanks.

If anyone could give me some pointers or know of a tutorial that relates to this I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

B

EDIT:  I have tried binding the table content of the table view to an Array Controller in IB with a Key Path of FinalResults and then on the save button sender

```
FinalResult's writeToFile:FilePath
```

FilePath being a location set using

```
set FilePath to choose folder
```

It is building successfully but when I press the Save button it is giving me the following error

014-03-11 22:37:07.462 SMPTE Grabber[4043:303] *** -[AppDelegate BackUp:]: Unrecognized function writeToFile_. (error -10000)

Do I need to somehow bind the table content to something else??

I have been at this for days now..

Thanks

B

Comment: Next Step: check out NSArray and it's writeToFile method.

Comment: Do I need to get the NSArray to reference the NSArrayController or the Table View, will that be done in the Bindings Inspector in IB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to StefanK over at Macscripter, he solved my original question whilst I was trying to solve it in a very round a bout way. (he must be a mind reader)

anyway I thought I would share it with anyone else who finds themselves in a similar predicament.

```
set filePath to POSIX path of (path to desktop) & "test.csv" -- sample path, change it something   appropriate
set theArray to arrayController's arrangedObjects() -- arrayController is a property connected   to an NSArrayController instance
set csvList to current application's NSMutableArray's array()
csvList's addObject:((theArray's objectAtIndex:0)'s allKeys()'s componentsJoinedByString:",")
repeat with anItem in theArray
  (csvList's addObject:((anItem's allValues())'s componentsJoinedByString:","))
end repeat
set csvText to (csvList's componentsJoinedByString:return)
csvText's writeToFile:filePath atomically:true encoding:(current application's    NSUTF8StringEncoding) |error|:(missing value)
```